# Comparar ISODate y ObjectId de dos json (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, date

Me gustaría comparar dos json, pero tengo problema con fechas y objetos. No se como puedo convertirlos o compararlos entre dos json para ver si son iguales o no.

JSON 1:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("85f84214452251fec9ac18"),
        "tarea" : {
            "fechaInicio" : ISODate("2017-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "fechaFin" : ISODate("2017-09-50T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "descripcion" : "texto",
         }
    }
```

JSON 2:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("99f9992251fec9999"),
        "tarea" : {
            "fechaInicio" : ISODate("2017-08-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "fechaFin" : ISODate("2017-08-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "descripcion" : "texto",
         }
    }
```

Este es un pequeño ejemplo, como veis el _id y las fechas son diferentes, pero no sé cómo convertirlos para poderlos comparar...
**¿Cómo puedo comparar los atributos ISODate y los ObjectId?**

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres comparar los objetos enteros puedes hacerlo ayudándote de la función `JSON.stringify`:

```
var a = JSON.stringify("{        \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"85f84214452251fec9ac18\"),        \"tarea\" : {            \"fechaInicio\" : ISODate(\"2017-09-30T00:00:00.000Z\"),            \"fechaFin\" : ISODate(\"2017-09-50T00:00:00.000Z\"),            \"descripcion\" : \"texto\",         }    }")
var b = JSON.stringify("{        \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"99f9992251fec9999\"),        \"tarea\" : {            \"fechaInicio\" : ISODate(\"2017-08-22T00:00:00.000Z\"),            \"fechaFin\" : ISODate(\"2017-08-25T00:00:00.000Z\"),            \"descripcion\" : \"texto\",         }    }")
a == b -> false
```

Otra opción sería trabajar con los objetos JSON y comparar sus atributos:

```
a = {
    "_id" : 'ObjectId("85f84214452251fec9ac18")',
    "tarea" : {
        "fechaInicio" : 'ISODate("2017-09-30T00:00:00.000Z")',
        "fechaFin" : 'ISODate("2017-09-50T00:00:00.000Z")',
        "descripcion" : "texto",
     }
}
b = {
    "_id" : 'ObjectId("99f9992251fec9999")',
    "tarea" : {
        "fechaInicio" : 'ISODate("2017-08-22T00:00:00.000Z")',
        "fechaFin" : 'ISODate("2017-08-25T00:00:00.000Z")',
        "descripcion" : "texto",
     }
}
```

De esta forma podrías comparar directamente los atributos uno a uno:

```
a._id == b._id -> false
a.tarea.fechaInicio == b.tarea.fechaInicio -> false
a.tarea.fechaFin == b.tarea.fechaFin -> false
```

Ten en cuenta que un objeto JSON siempre se compone de una colección de pares nombre:valor (o de una lista), por lo tanto ObjectId y ISODate no son atributos sino valores de _id y fechaInicio/fechaFin.